# a win app load and close when the user login/logout

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, logout

I want to write a win app,and i want to get the time of login/logout of any users in my local network.how can i make this app that starts when the user turn on the windows is becomming run,i don't want to put in startUp folder.
I want if the user loging off my app become close and then the user login it becoms run.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the Startup folder? That's what it's for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a record into the windows registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

You can use the `SessionEnding` event to detect when a user is logging off

```
static void Main()
{
    Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndingEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnding);
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}

static void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndingEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: you mean i should put my *.exe file in this "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" is it true??and it becomes run every time the user login??

Comment: Just put the path to the executable file. You don't need to copy the whole file content into the registry.

Comment: thank you very much,how can i set the path of installed my app's exe to the registry wit my app or setup file????

Comment: you can set it using the following code. `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rk = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run");
            rk.SetValue("MyAppName", @"C:\WhereMyAppIs\MyApp.exe");` Or you can get the installer to set it.